Given the data of points, can they always be fitted to some implicit function?
So recently I was wondering, if you were given data in which was $n$ amount of point coordinates in a 2D cartesian coordinate system, can these $n$ points always be fitted to some implicit function? if not, then what conditions should this data satisfy?

What do you mean? If you have $n+1$ points $(x_0, y_0), \dots, (x_n, y_n)$, then you can, say, fit an $n$ degree polynomial $p$ such that $p(x_i) = y_i$ for $i = 0, \dots, n$.

It gets more complicated , if the $x_i$ need not be distinct , but there should still be an implicite polynomial equation satisfied by the points. Whether this is a good fit is a completely different story.

Per the comments, if the $x_i$ are distinct, then it's trivial to fit a polynomial of degree $n-1$ to the data.
If the $x_i$ are not distinct, rotate the system so they are: if there are only finitely many points, this is always possible$^\dagger$. Fit a polynomial $Y=P(X)$ in the new coordinates, and rotate back (which gives you an implicit function).
Proving ($\dagger$) is quite a nice exercise; a sketch is below.

 Imagine rotating the system through an angle $\theta$ about $O$. With finitely many points, there are only finitely many different ways to pair up points having matching $x$-coordinates, and so only finitely many values of $\theta$ that don't work.


Thanks got it <333
